# Get numbers by length that can repeat

Tags: java, regex

I'm kind of noob with regex, but i couldn't find an answer (or I didn't do the right research) to this problem.

I have a bunch of numbers for example 17653133062491 and I need to get the groups of 5 consecutive numbers between 1 - 9 but if I do somehting like [1-9]{5} y get 17653, 62491. What I need to get is 17653, 76531, 65313, 53133, 62491.

Any tip?

Thanks!

Edit for the record: The answer of anubhava is correct. But if you try to do something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("?=([1-9]{5})");
```

You will get a nice exception:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
```

Just add an extra parenthesis and get group 1, like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=([1-9]{13}))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);        
while(matcher.find()) {
        String match = matcher.group(1);
        .....
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
(?=([1-9]{5}))
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY1dR1/1)

You will get 5 matches with this regex (shown in **MATCH INFORMATION** of the given demo link) because lookahead is zero-width assertion.

Comment: Thanks! I'll bokmark the demo. Added some code and exception I got (didn't add outer brackets).

Comment: Yes `(?=...)` is the syntax for positive lookahead. Also check the linked tutorial on lookarounds.